# Import eps files in inkscape 092 1 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, inkscape

I'm trying to import an eps file in Ubuntu 16.04, inkscape 0.92 and got this error:

```
ps2pdf failed:
GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Can't find initialization file gs_init.ps.
```

Comment: `/usr/share/ghostscript/9.26/Resource/Init/gs_init.ps` should be provided by `libgs9-common` - check that the file exists and if not maybe try re-installing that package

Comment: I faced the same problem. As the file from the error message exists in the location @steeldriver mentioned, I filed a bug report: https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/issues/531

Comment: Might be the files (or in particular the file creator/generator)? Could you post an example. It works for me and I've updated the bug report and added an example file that works here. If it's output from Adobe then maybe there are extensions that are interfering; might work if you run it through eps2eps or similar. Does it open with `okular`, or equivalent viewers?

Answer (score 3):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04, I had installed inkscape through the Ubuntu Software center and had the same problem.
I have uninstalled inkscape and installed it again through:

```
sudo apt  install inkscape
```

This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu Software there are 2 versions of Inkscape the one with snap (most recent version) and the legacy.
The Snap version was the one failing for me.

[image: Ubuntu Software searching Inkscape]

I've replaced it by the legacy version that fixed the issue.

Comment: A bug report on this issue has now closed indicating the Snap should now work. See https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inkscape/-/issues/1406#what-happened